# WPF How to Bind an Image to a DataGrid column as a property of the ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm creating a WPF app using the MVVM design pattern.

I have a DataGrid with 4 columns and I want the last column to be a column of Images. The other 3 text columns are bound to the properties of an `AttributeNode` contained in the list `Attributes`, which is used as the `ItemsSource`.

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:AttributeGridViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>     

...

<DataGrid Name="AttributeGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter" Binding="{Binding Parameter}"
                            MinWidth="30" Width="225" FontSize="15"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"
                            MinWidth="30" Width="*" FontSize="15"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Address" Binding="{Binding IpAddress}"
                            MinWidth="10" Width="120" FontSize="15"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Conflict" Width="50">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- area of confusion -->
                    <Image Source="{Binding ???}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**AttributeGridViewModel & AttributeNode**

In my `AttributeGridViewModel` I set the Attributes using a line like this:

```
Attributes = ConfigUtility.GetAttributeNodes(value);
```

Below is part of the `AttributeNode` class :

```
public class AttributeNode
{
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource {get; set; }
    public char Type { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

You can see the properties here and how I attach the Parameter, Value, and IpAddress properties to their own columns.

But if I try to do this with the Image Source binding then I get this error :

[image]

**Question**

I'm not sure yet if I can bind to a string that represents an Image path but I guess more importantly is how can I access and data bind to the property `ImageSource` for an item of type `AttributeNode` in the the ItemsSource `Attributes` (a list of `Attributes`)for the DataGrid? My implementation works for the other 3 columns and updates correctly based on changes in my ViewModel. How do I access the property like I did previously?

Comment: Just a guess: Does it help if you define the DataTemplate as a static resource, as shown in the MSDN sample for DataGridTemplateColumn? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DaveMackersie I get the same error I was getting before.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody wondering how I resolved this issue...

It appears it is a Resharper issue and creating a new `Attribute` like this

```
new Attribute("","","","../Icons/checkmark.png")
```

works even though Resharper claims it can't find the `ImageSource` property. The DataContext is set correctly during run time. The Images show up in the column now.